# How to customize spaCy's tokenizer to preclude splitting phrases described by a regular expression

Tags: nlp, spacy

For example I want the tokenizer to tokenize 'New York' as ['New York'] instead of the default ['New', 'York'].

The docs suggest adding regular expressions when creating a custom tokenizer.

So I did the following:

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

target = re.compile(r'New York')

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):

    dflt_prefix = nlp.Defaults.prefixes
    dflt_suffix = nlp.Defaults.suffixes
    dflt_infix = nlp.Defaults.infixes

    prefix_re = spacy.util.compile_prefix_regex(dflt_prefix).search
    suffix_re = spacy.util.compile_suffix_regex(dflt_suffix).search
    infix_re = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(dflt_infix).finditer

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re,
                                suffix_search=suffix_re,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re,
                                token_match=target.match)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
doc = nlp(u"New York")
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

I used the defaults so that normal behaviour continues unless the function target (the argument for the token_match parameter) returns true.

But I am still getting ['New', 'York']. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`PhraseMatcher`](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher) component to identify the phrases you want to treat as single tokens. Use the [`doc.retokenize`](https://spacy.io/api/doc#retokenize) context manager to merge the tokens in your phrase into a single token. Finally, wrap the entire process in [custom pipeline component](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-attributes), and add the component to your language model.

```
import spacy
from spacy.lang.en import English
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Doc

class MatchRetokenizeComponent:
  def __init__(self, nlp, terms):
    self.terms = terms
    self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
    patterns = [nlp.make_doc(text) for text in terms]
    self.matcher.add("TerminologyList", None, *patterns)
    Doc.set_extension("phrase_matches", getter=self.matcher, force=True) # You should probably set Force=False

  def __call__(self, doc):
    matches = self.matcher(doc)
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            retokenizer.merge(doc[start:end], attrs={"LEMMA": str(doc[start:end])})
    return doc

terms = ["Barack Obama", "Angela Merkel", "Washington, D.C."]

nlp = English()
retokenizer = MatchRetokenizeComponent(nlp, terms) 
nlp.add_pipe(retokenizer, name='merge_phrases', last=True)

doc = nlp("German Chancellor Angela Merkel and US President Barack Obama "
          "converse in the Oval Office inside the White House in Washington, D.C.")

[tok for tok in doc]

#[German,
# Chancellor,
# Angela Merkel,
# and,
# US,
# President,
# Barack Obama,
# converse,
# in,
# the,
# Oval,
# Office,
# inside,
# the,
# White,
# House,
# in,
# Washington, D.C.]
```

EDIT: The PhraseMatcher will actually throw errors if you end up trying to merge overlapping spans. If this is an issue, you might be better off using the new [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/api/entityruler), which tries to stick with the longest contiguous match. Using entities like this let's us simplify our custom pipeline component a bit:

```
class EntityRetokenizeComponent:
  def __init__(self, nlp):
    pass
  def __call__(self, doc):
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for ent in doc.ents:
            retokenizer.merge(doc[ent.start:ent.end], attrs={"LEMMA": str(doc[ent.start:ent.end])})
    return doc


nlp = English()

ruler = EntityRuler(nlp)

# I don't care about the entity label, so I'm just going to call everything an "ORG"
ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "ORG", "pattern": term} for term in terms])
nlp.add_pipe(ruler) 

retokenizer = EntityRetokenizeComponent(nlp)
nlp.add_pipe(retokenizer, name='merge_phrases')
```

Comment: Is it possible to supply regular expressions for a token to a Phrasematcher?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the "regex" in your question is an exact match, which it definitely supports. It also supports ignoring case and matching on lemmas and other things like that through the `attr` argument, which determins which token attribute to match against. If the PhraseMatcher or EntityRuler aren't powerful enough for you, you could look at the pattern API for the lower-level Matcher class.